# Specify Firebase Database Url C#

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to specify my Database url. thi is the issue
DatabaseException:

> Failed to get FirebaseDatabase instance: Specify DatabaseURL within FirebaseApp or from your GetInstance() call.Firebase.Database.FirebaseDatabase.GetInstance (Firebase.FirebaseApp app, System.String url).

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the configuration that you use for Firebase doesn't include a database URL, which your code needs.

As the error message says, you can pass the URL in the call to `GetInstance()`.

So:

1. Look up the database URL in the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/_/data),
2. Find the call to `GetInstance()` in your code.
3. Pass the URL to that call.